# Spring Integration Http Outbound Gateway Header Mapper

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am trying to add custom headers to my http outbound gateway.

Things that I have tried & work:

```
<int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="replyChannel" value="nullChannel" /> 
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/xml" />
        <int:header name="X-Operation" value="CUSTOM_OPERATION" />
        <int:header name="X-StatusCode" value="200" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int-http:outbound-gateway url="${custom.url}/update"
        mapped-request-headers="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Operation, StatusCode"        
        http-method="POST" request-factory="serviceRequestFactory"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" 
        error-handler="errorChannelHandler" />
```

In the above scenario, it works but the custom headers that I add, are prefixed with X- by default.

To get rid of it, I tried the following but it doesn't set my custom values to the headers:

```
<int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="replyChannel" value="nullChannel" /> 
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/xml" />
        <int:header name="Operation" value="CUSTOM_OPERATION" />
        <int:header name="StatusCode" value="200" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int-http:outbound-gateway url="${custom.url}/update"
        header-mapper="headerMapper"        
        http-method="POST" request-factory="serviceRequestFactory"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" 
        error-handler="errorChannelHandler" />

<bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*"/>
    <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Operation, StatusCode" />
    <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value=""/>
</bean>
```

After spending a lot of time in trying to fix this, I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your mapper with the sample app and it worked fine...

```
<int:gateway id="requestGateway" 
             service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.http.RequestGateway"
             default-request-channel="requestChannel">
     <int:default-header name="Operation" value="foo" />
     <int:default-header name="StatusCode" value="bar" />
</int:gateway>

<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel" 
                           url="http://localhost:18080/http/receiveGateway"
                           http-method="POST"
                           header-mapper="headerMapper"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"/>

<bean id="headerMapper"
    class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
    <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Operation, StatusCode" />
    <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
</bean>


POST /http/receiveGateway HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/plain, */*
Operation: foo
StatusCode: bar
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept-Charset: big5, ...
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_60
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 5
```

Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` to get detailed logging for header mapping...

```
11:13:19.562 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[operation] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=operation
11:13:19.562 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] setting headerName=[Operation], value=foo
11:13:19.563 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[errorchannel] WILL NOT be mapped
11:13:19.563 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[id] WILL NOT be mapped
11:13:19.563 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[statuscode] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=statuscode
11:13:19.563 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] setting headerName=[StatusCode], value=bar
```

Comment: Thank you Gary! I was doing this inside a <chain> so it did not work until I had set the overwrite=true for the header enricher. My bad, I forgot to mention that I was trying this inside a chain.

Comment: @Gary Is there any place i can find the java config for the Http outbound gateway?

Comment: I just submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2102) that adds some examples to the reference manual.