# Appending X to Custom Request Headers in Spring-Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I found that when I want to make a REST call using Spring-Integration, it automatically appends 'x' in case its a custom header.

For example in Spring-integration while sending custom request headers such as `API-KEY`, the actual request header name in the API call becomes `X-API-KEY` and so it fails.

It seems like Spring is standardizing by enforcing the Custom request headers to start with X, is there a work around?

```
<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="httpHeaderEnricherChannel"/>
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
                                       url="http://localhost:9090/balance"
                                       http-method="GET"
                                       mapped-request-headers="Api-Key"
                                       expected-response-type="java.lang.String"/>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="httpHeaderEnricherChannel" 
                     output-channel="requestChannel">
    <int:header name="Api-Key" value="pass"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.outboundMapper()` bean with the `setUserDefinedHeaderPrefix(null)` and including that your custom `Api-Key` header mapping. After that you should replace `mapped-request-headers` attribute with the `header-mapper` reference.

We have revised the feature and decided to remove "X-" default prefix in the next version.

For more info please, see here [Custom HTTP headers : naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions) and here https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3903.

Comment: This fixed the issue but, I didn't understand why userDefinedHeaderPrefix has to be null

Comment: Otherwise the non-standard header is prepended with the `X-` prefix and target service misses that new `X-Api-Key`

Comment: I am trying to use the header-enricher, will the input and output Chanel be same as request and reply Chanel

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please, start a new SO thread with more info

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Artem for clarifying, and Gary's post here [Spring Integration Http Outbound Gateway Header Mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295750/spring-integration-http-outbound-gateway-header-mapper)

I was able to solve the issue

```
<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>
<int:gateway id="requestGateway" 
             service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.http.RequestGateway"
             default-request-channel="requestChannel">
            <int:default-header name="Api-Key" value="pass" />
</int:gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
                           header-mapper="headerMapper"
                           url="http://localhost:9090/balance"
                           http-method="GET"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"/>

<beans:bean id="headerBean"
            class="org.springframework.integration.samples.http.HeaderBean" />

<bean id="headerMapper"
    class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
    <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Api-Key" />
    <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
</bean>
```

Comment: That's great to hear that you overcame your issue, but it is sad do not see acceptance for the answer. I'd disable here on SO the "answer" functionality for requestors...

Comment: @Artem I can accept my answer after 2 days, if you think I should accept yours, will do that. Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @ArtemBilan In that case, please have a look here :). This question of mine has not been addressed for a while.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039632/rest-api-layer-orchestration-using-spring-integration